# Unable to SSL Godaddy verified certificate on AWS EC2 (Ubuntu) apache system

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04

I am unable to ssl my website ainoapp.io, although i can use https://www.ainoapp.io/ as all our pages show up correctly however, site is still not secure.

[image: site is not secure]

Here are steps that i did on EC2 ubuntu apache system (after Godaddy approved the certificate).

1. enabled ssl and header module
2. uploaded files c969b7f1a54c0a63.crt and gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt to  /etc/apache2/ssl
3. created two conf files in /etc/apache2/sites-available: ainosite.conf and  ainosite-ssl.conf
4. enabled default-ssl.conf, ainosite-ssl.conf and ainosite.conf such that sites-enabled has these entries only.
5. EC2 instance accept inbound traffic 443
6. port.conf listen to port 80 and 443
7. restart apache

Below are the snippets:

[image: ainosite-ssl.conf]

[image: ainosite.conf]

Am I missing something here, any ideas would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrutinize the wording of the error (warning) message carefully.

The browser is not really complaining about your SSL configuration.

It's complaining that you're being inconsistent with the images on the page -- they are still `<img src="http://...` instead of also using HTTPS (or being relative links, or protocol agnostic).

I believe this is also referred to as a "mixed content" warning.

Comment: Thank you sir, I should have checked references in my pages first.